# Remove CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS from a column in a firebird database

Tags: sql, unicode, firebird, alter, sql-types

I have a Firebird database with several tables in it. There are several columns who were added when database was created as

```
alter table Machines add MachineVersion varchar(100) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS
```

I want to modify these columns to drop the `CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS` so I ran the command

```
alter table Machines alter column MachineVersion type VARCHAR(100)
```

Still, when I open the database in SQL Manager the character set for these columns is still UNICODE_FSS.

Is there another syntax for the second command to remove the `CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter table Machines alter column MachineVersion type VARCHAR(100)
```

This query won't change the character set.

If you want to remove charater set you should alter domain like:

```
update RDB$FIELDS set
RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = NULL
where RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$141'
```

Instead of RDB$141 use column domain

Comment: Note that this will no longer work with Firebird 3. Creating a new column and copying the data is the only way to drop the character set (or: revert it to `none`)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add new column , copy data from old column to new and later to drop old column?

Comment: I cannot do that because of existing triggers in the database.

Comment: Well, do not drop old column ;-) Change old field to new in trigger body.